# Group by a data frame by a column using threshold or cutoff from another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, inner-join

I have a data frame, df_ret, that includes daily returns for a stock with an ID. It is daily, so that gives me 1762 rows. It's from 2010-01-04 to 2016-12-30.

```
> head(df_ret)
  permno       date         ret  gvkey
1  54594 2010-01-04  0.03437776 001004
2  54594 2010-01-05  0.01935209 001004
3  54594 2010-01-06  0.05035086 001004
4  54594 2010-01-07  0.01571708 001004
5  54594 2010-01-08 -0.01586073 001004
6  54594 2010-01-11 -0.01139941 001004
```

I have another data frame which also have an ID column but has only 8 rows:

```
> df_fun
gvkey   datadate fyear fyr       at     sale sich
1 001004 2010-05-31  2009   5 1501.042 1352.151 5080
2 001004 2011-05-31  2010   5 1703.727 1775.782 5080
3 001004 2012-05-31  2011   5 2195.653 2074.498 5080
4 001004 2013-05-31  2012   5 2136.900 2167.100 5080
5 001004 2014-05-31  2013   5 2199.500 2035.000 5080
6 001004 2015-05-31  2014   5 1515.000 1594.300 5080
7 001004 2016-05-31  2015   5 1442.100 1662.600 5080
8 001004 2017-05-31  2016   5 1504.100 1767.600 5080
```

datadate column indicates the end of a fiscal year. What I'd like to achieve is that I want to group df_ret by fiscal year and sum up returns, so that I end up with 8 rows as well. But I'd like to do this by using datadate column of the second data frame as cutoff points. Then I will join the two by gvkey, obviously; or, should I first join and then group by? How? In the end, I want it to look like:

```
> df_merged
   gvkey   datadate fyear fyr       at     sale sich return
1 001004 2010-05-31  2009   5 1501.042 1352.151 5080 0.12
2 001004 2011-05-31  2010   5 1703.727 1775.782 5080 0.11
3 001004 2012-05-31  2011   5 2195.653 2074.498 5080 -0.18
4 001004 2013-05-31  2012   5 2136.900 2167.100 5080 0.06
5 001004 2014-05-31  2013   5 2199.500 2035.000 5080 0.22
6 001004 2015-05-31  2014   5 1515.000 1594.300 5080 0.06
7 001004 2016-05-31  2015   5 1442.100 1662.600 5080 -0.12
8 001004 2017-05-31  2016   5 1504.100 1767.600 5080 0.05
```

Any help is appreciated; thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to merge the 2 dataframes, then filter to get relevant rows and then group by using ddply on ret

```
library(dplyr)

df_temp <- merge(df_ret,df_fun)
df_temp<-df_temp[ ((df_temp$datadate - df_temp$date)<366)&((df_temp$datadate - df_temp$date)>0),]

df_merged <-ddply(df_temp,c('id', 'weight','fyear','fyr'), summarize,
at=mean(at),
sale=mean(sale), 
sich=mean(sich),
return = prod(1+ret) -1 )
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver Ashish, thank you so much! Can you explain how the first lines of the code got rid of the unnecessary rows?

Comment: Happy to help! For the filtering row, we need to take the difference between the datadate and date, and make sure it lies between 366 and 0! (i.e. only selecting the rows where the date lies in the correct fyear)

Comment: Got it, I appreciate it!

Comment: Great! If you're satisfied with the answer, you can accept it as the best answer for this question! :)

Comment: I just did :) Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! All the best for your quant analysis!